# How to transform a json structure into another

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, node.js

How to transform that JSON structure

```
{
            "14400": [
              [
                1526529600,
                0.00006651,
                1478955,
                99.320145
              ],
              [
                1526544000,
                0.00006816,
                1378670,
                95.26538
              ],
              [
                1526558400,
                0.0000682,
                1270402,
                85.7694
              ]
            ] 
    }
```

Into that one:

```
[0.00006651, 0.00006816, 0.0000682]
```

So how to put each 2nd element form each list above into another list?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try with:

```
Object.values(data).reduce((acc, items) => acc.concat(items.map(item => item[1])), []);
```

Comment: There is definitely a canonical duplicate out there that solves this problem.

Comment: @Jordan.J.D Feel free to link it.

Answer (score 0):

```
newList = []
for (let i = 0; i < originalList['14400'].length; i++) {
    newList.push(originalList['14400'][i][1])
}
```

that should do it :)